# Delete AF_UNIX file automatically?

Tags: file, sockets, ipc, bind, shutdown

Is there a way to delete the file created by AF_UNIX bind() operation automatically if the process crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not.

You can however remove it when you start up, before you (re)create the socket.

On e.g. [linux](http://linux.die.net/man/7/unix) you can avoid creating an entry in the file system by having the `sun_path` start with a 0 byte - this creates an "abstract"  socket that isn't visible in the filsystem - see the mentioned man page for more info, and thus vanishes when the process exits. It's not entierly clear to me whether that is a standard feature or if it is linux specific.

Comment: Abstract namespace is not an option as I need this code to be portable. Deleting he file is not an option either because the process may have not crashed and thus I would delete it's file while it is alive. Is there at least a way to check whether given file is currently being used?